# workbookfactory for getting a file is throwing error

Tags: selenium, apache-poi

I am a selenium beginner,
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("C:\Documents\Landing_page.xls");
Workbook wb = new  WorkbookFactory(fis);
I am getting compilation error for executing the above 2 lines even after importing all neccessary jar files

Comment: Try using double slashes to the file name.. C:\\Documents\\Landing_page.xls

Comment: If that does not work, share the exception details.

Comment: workbookfactory.create(fis) has to be used instead of creating an instance of workbookfactory. Worked after changing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [JavaDocs for WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html), you'll see it isn't a class you instantiate.

Instead, what you want to do is, as taken from [the POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream):

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("MyExcel.xls"));
```

You need call the [create(File)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create%28java.io.File%29) method, and you'll want to use the [File directly rather than an InputStream](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) for lower memory.